# calculate tangent

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Its been a while since classes in trigonometry, I am calculating the height of rockets.  I know that the formula is (distance from base) * Tangent(angle of rocket height).  The trick is I will not be in a place where there will be a calculator.  How can I do this manually?

Comment: Do you have a rough estimate for the angle beforehand? For example is it going to be around 20 degrees, or around 70 degrees?

Comment: I'm going to guess about 30 degrees 50 feet away average

Answer (score 1):

Similar triangles.  Point a stick at the apogee of the rocket.  The ratio of the height of the tip of the stick to the base distance along a level is the same as the ration of the height of the apogee to the level base distance of the apogee.  Then it is a matter of a multiplication and a division which you should be able to do without a calculator.

It was a school exercise a long time ago to measure the heights of trees this way.  It is also the basis of surveying.

Hope this helps.

Ced